# How to use the 'Insert' key on an external keyboard with macOS?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I connected an external Logitech wireless USB keyboard to a MacBook Pro. Generally the keyboard works fine. But the **Insert** key (present on this external keyboard, is not present on the MacBook's built-in keyboard) and does literally *nothing*.

Even in the [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) application (a keyboard layout editor) this key does nothing.

Short question is: **How to make this key visible to macOS?**

Long question is: how to make this key work in following use cases:

1. VIM running in terminal: switching COMMAND/INSERT/REPLACE modes.
2. Using SHIFT+INSERT for inserting text from clipboard in any application.

Note: I know how to do (1) and (2) by other ways, like command+V for insert and i/R in VIM. That's not an issue here. The issue is only the usage of a very handy INSERT key.

Comment: It's now 2021 and this remains a problem.  May I add more debug to this question?   I don't have an inkling of an answer so posting in there will get flagged as NAA, and a comment won't hold formatting.

Comment: If the answer below doesn’t work @Criggie , I would suggest asking a more narrow question if you need a different workaround than the (1) and (2) above which the OP requested.

Answer (score 2):

macOS has no concept of an Insert key.
It doesn't exist on Mac & if you use a Windows/PC keyboard with one [on the 10-key pad] it will likely interpret it as the 'Clear All' key for Calculator.